# Save data to another table when do post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have new table in wordpress like:

*id*

*title*

*category*

How to save that data to another table that I created while post article in wordpress?

Comment: i mean when i do post, suddenly title and category are saved in my new table

Comment: Research for `save_post` and `$wpdb`.

Comment: thanks brasofile, $wpdb is what I need, but i'm confuse where i put it  ? i want save data to my new table in same time where post article

of course it should be put in same function, sorry i'm still new in WP

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved

i just edit file in wp-includes/post.php

add `$wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_newarticle', 
        array( 
            'title' => 'title',

            'category'=>'category',
            'post_id'=>'post_ID',
            'status'=>'status'
        )
        );`

in function wp_insert_post( )

so when i post something, directly the data also save in table wp_newarticle